# cannot pass PHP variable to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, quoting

I cannot invoke a Javascript function if I try to pass a PHP array element as an arg.
I've tried everything (except the right thing, I suppose).

Here is the PHP code -- the 2nd line is the one that is failing:

```
var_dump($theRow[11]);
$htmlBuffer = '<div onclick="showIt(' . $theRow[11] . ')">does not work!</div>';
$htmlBuffer = $htmlBuffer . '<div onclick="showIt()"> THIS WORKS FINE! </div>';
```

Here is the HTML code to output the above:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <?php echo '<div id="listSection">' . $htmlBuffer . '</div>'; 
      ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript function 'showIt()':

```
function showIt(theVal)
{
   alert("HERE IS WHAT WAS PASSED IN: " + theVal);              
}
```

Here is the output on the page:

**1)  First I see this on the page:**

```
string(8) "52e43c33"
```

Now, that is 100% fine. That is what I expect to see at array position #11.
Note that 'theRow[11]' is a PHP array, where each array element is an 8-digit (hex) number.  And that var_dump() call shows that the array element at position 11 is a valid 8-digit (hex) number, and that's what I expect to find there.  So that is okay.

**2) then I see this on the page:**

```
does not work!  
THIS WORKS FINE!
```

When I click on "THIS WORKS FINE!"  on my web page, I see an alert box appear that says this:

```
HERE IS WHAT WAS PASSED IN: undefined
```

Now that is okay by me.  I did not pass a parameter to showIt() for the line of code I clicked on.  The fact that the alert() box appears shows 100% certainty that the onclick() is working.

AND HERE IS THE FAILURE:  when I click on the line of text in the browser window:

```
**does not work!**
```

-- which is *trying* to pass theRow[11]  as the argument to showIt() -- the alert box does that's called in showIt() not appear.

I figured "okay this is a quoting issue."

SO I TRIED THESE to no avail:

```
$htmlBuffer = '<div onclick="showIt(\'' . $theRow[11] . '\')">does not work!</div>';
$htmlBuffer = '<div onclick="showIt(\"' . $theRow[11] . '\")">does not work!</div>';
$htmlBuffer = '<div onclick="showIt("' . $theRow[11] . '")">does not work!</div>';
$htmlBuffer = '<div onclick="showIt($theRow[11])">does not work!</div>';
```

NONE OF MY quoting attempts here succeeded.

How do I properly quote the line of code:

```
$htmlBuffer = '<div onclick="showIt(' . $theRow[11] . ')">does not work!</div>';
```

to get theRow[11] successfully passed to showIt()?

**EDIT:  here is the 'View source' of the page:**

```
string(8) "7ab79992"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function showIt(theVal)
       {
         alert("HERE IS WHAT WAS PASSED IN: " + theVal);              
       }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div id="listSection"><div onclick="showIt(7ab79992)">does not work!</div>
    <div onclick="showIt()"> THIS WORKS FINE! </div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the html code (not the screen output) that is generated?

Comment: open the javascript debugger and see if there is an error.

Comment: @KristenJukowski  I have added the 'view source' output at the end of my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a tip: is easy to read if you append the string with: `$htmlBuffer .= "Something else";` that is equivalent to `$htmlBuffer = $htmlBuffer . "Something else";`

If you are 100% sure that the content of `$theRow[11]` is the string `"52e43c33"` this version would be working:

```
$htmlBuffer = '';
$htmlBuffer .= '<div onclick="showIt(\'' . $theRow[11] . '\');">does not work!</div>';
```

The important part is that you are quoting the javascript string using `'` so you must be sure that the php content of `$theRow[11]` must not have any `'`. Is easy to use `'` to quote the javascript argument string because you are opening the HTML attribute with `"`. Remove the other lines that you are trying because thats can cause unbalanced quotes.

Check the output of your browser (use `view-source:URL`) you must see something like:

```
<div onclick="showIt('52e43c33');">does not work!</div>
```

Comment: That worked.  I thought I had already tried this very sequence **\''**.  However, I don't understand why **\"'**  would fail to work.  But it doesn't.  Thanks Emilio.

Answer (score 1):

How about a little [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to avoid all that nasty quoting/escaping?

```
$htmlBuffer = <<<EOD
<div onclick="showIt('$theRow[11]')">does not work!</div>
EOD;
```

Comment: Thanks.  The reason I'm so freaking frustrated is I'm no stranger to quoting or heredocs.  I am going to figure out why my original code isn't working because I need to fill this gap in my knowledge I have.  I loved heredocs.  Not using one here though -- I'm determined to figure out what the tweak to my code is for the sake of broadening my quoting knowledge.

Comment: Honestly your first attempt looks correct to me (of the "SO I TRIED THESE"). GO back to that and look at the generated HTML, maybe add it to the question if it's still not working.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I was decent at quoting.  This one is kicking my azz.  I've been 4 hours at this simple thing.  There have been a couple different attempts I tried that from past experience I *knew* should work but they didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <html>
 <body>

   <div id="listSection">
     <div onclick="showIt(<? echo $theRow[11] ; ?>)">does not work!
     </div>
   </div>
   <!--and this too-->
   <!--<?php echo "<div id="listSection"><div onclick=".'"'."showIt($theRow[11]".'"'.">does not work!</div>" ; ?>-->

 </body>
 </html>
```

well I have not checked this but it has always worked for me this way.

Good Luck !!